# keycreator:21: attempt to perform arithetic on local 'iLevel' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null

Getting "keycreator:21: attempt to perform arithetic on local 'iLevel' (a nil value)" and cannot understand/figure out why

```
local sPrefix = "Class "              
local sSufix = " Keycard"             
local iLevelLength = 6                
local sDiskSide = "right"             


local tVarargs = {...}
local iLevel = tVarargs[1]
local sLevel = "4"

if (iLevel == "1") then sLevel = "E" end
if (iLevel == "2") then sLevel = "D" end
if (iLevel == "3") then sLevel = "C" end
if (iLevel == "4") then sLevel = "B" end
if (iLevel == "5") then sLevel = "A" end

local hMKey = fs.open("masterkey.lua", "r")
local hKey = fs.open("disk/key", "w")
local sMKey = hMKey.readAll()
local sWriteKey = string.sub(sMKey, 1, iLevel*iLevelLength)

disk.setLabel(sDiskSide, sPrefix .. sLevel .. sSufix)
hKey.write(sWriteKey)

hMKey.close()
hKey.close()
```

Comment: The `...` only works when declared as a function parameter. If this is a standalone script, use `arg` instead of `{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Lua 5.3 Reference Manual:

[3.4 - Expressions](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4)

> Vararg expressions, denoted by three dots ('...'), can only be used
>   when directly inside a vararg function; they are explained in §3.4.11.

[7 - Lua Standalone:](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7)

> Before running any code, lua collects all command-line arguments in a
>   global table called arg. The script name goes to index 0, the first
>   argument after the script name goes to index 1, and so on.

So in your case `{...}` results in an empty table. Use `arg` instead.